# How can I get video details from the node @vimeo/vimeo lib?

Tags: node.js, next.js, vimeo, web-frontend, vimeo-api

I am trying to get details about videos in my library, specifically the thumbnails and duration, but I am getting an error response.

I am using Next.JS, and I am making my request in getStaticProps which runs on the server.

My request looks like this:

```
import { Vimeo } from '@vimeo/vimeo';

export async function getStaticProps() {
  let client = new Vimeo(`${clientId}`, `${clientSecret}`, `${accessToken}`);
  client.request(
    {
      method: 'GET',
      path: `/videos/796808098`,
    },
    function (error, body, status_code, headers) {
      if (error) {
        console.log(error);
      }

      console.log(body);
    }
  );

  return {
    props: {},
  };
}
```

And the error response I get is:

```
{"error":"The requested video couldn't be found."}
```

I have also tried using fetch as an alternative to the node package, which returned the exact same error. Here is the code:

```
fetch('https://api.vimeo.com/videos/796808098', {
    headers: {
      Authorization: `bearer ${accessToken}`,
      'content-type': 'application/json',
    },
  })
    .then(res => {
      const json = res.json();
      return json;
    })
    .then(json => {
      return json
    });
```

That video definitely exists in my library, but I am wondering if my app does not have access to all the videos in my library? Another thought I had was there was a problem finding the video because it is nested in a folder, but even adding the folder name to the video id does not help.

As a note, when I followed the Vimeo set up docs, I was able to make the request to /tutorial, and the response had verified that my client id, access token, and client secret were all functioning properly.

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out!

The access token I had created did not have permission to read video data. The solution was to go into my app, scroll to the access token section, generate a new token, select the "Private" checkbox, and select the "Video" checkbox.